# de que forma puedo formatear un dato tipo datetime a string en c#?

Tags: c#, arraylist, datetime

tengo un problema con el programa, que tengo en concreto, pero lo demas todo bien.
De que forma podre ingresar una fecha de tipo date time("dd/mm/yyyy"), para llevarlo a string?

Clase Articulo

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Inventario
{
    public class Articulo
    {
        private int id;
        private string nombre;
        private string categoria;
        private int cantidad;
        private double precio;
        private DateTime fechaIngreso;

        public int Id
        {
            get { return id; }
            set { id = value; }
        }

        public string Nombre
        {
            get { return nombre; }
            set { nombre = value; }
        }

        public string Categoria
        {
            get { return categoria; }
            set { categoria = value; }
        }

        public int Cantidad
        {
            get { return cantidad; }
            set { cantidad = value; }
        }

        public double Precio
        {
            get { return precio; }
            set { precio = value; }
        }

        public DateTime FechaIngreso
        {
            get { return fechaIngreso; }
            set { fechaIngreso = value; }
        }

        public Articulo()
        {

        }
       
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "Id: " + id.ToString() + "\nNombre: " + nombre.ToString() + "\nCategoria: " + categoria.ToString() +
                "\nCantidad: " + cantidad.ToString() + "\nPrecio: " + precio.ToString()+"\nFecha: "+fechaIngreso.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Aca mi Class program para poder ingresar la fecha, no le atino mucho a los tipos de datetime.
aca estoy usando list<>.
Se que se usa algo de un format pero no se como aplicarlo a este caso, aca tengo mi codigo la clase y el main que seria este.

```
Console.WriteLine("Ingrese Fecha");
                        //  ar.FechaIngreso = 
                        a.Add(ar);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes intentar transformando el tipado de tu variable con la función .ToString.
Sí estas trabajando con una variable de tipo de datetime, ella tiene por defecto (en realidad es más complejo de eso) la función .ToString

En tu caso debería ser similar a:

```
fechaIngreso.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Revisá más de la documentación [acá](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=net-6.0)
Revisá deferentes formatos de fecha [acá](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/date-and-time-format-in-c-sharp-programming1)

Comment: gracias amigo,  me resulto

Comment: Esta debería ser la respuesta aceptada. Provee los links a la documentación, y lo más importante, los formatos de fecha, que siempre se nos olvidan y tenemos que buscarlos una y otra vez.

Answer (score 2):

Hola puedes usar ToString("Formato")

```
fechaIngreso.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

Puedes ponerlo asi:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return "Id: " + id.ToString() + "\nNombre: " + nombre.ToString() + "\nCategoria: " + categoria.ToString() +
        "\nCantidad: " + cantidad.ToString() + "\nPrecio: " + precio.ToString()+"\nFecha: "+fechaIngreso.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
}
```

Comment: seria aplicarlo en program? cierto?

Comment: cuando lo llamo en program, seria ar.fechaIngreso=Console.readline();?

Comment: me resulto amigo al convert la fecha en program , gracias